# Shopify - Jquery not executing

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am trying to execute a Jquery in my shopify page. However Jquery is not getting executed. When I use the same code in jsfiddle, the code is working(I get the alert message, but when I execute same jquery in shopify, i get no alert message).

Here is link to jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tusharacc/ck84ad6z/1/

The code is same as I am using in shopify.

The HTML code is included in index.liquid. The javascript is uploaded into Assets folder.

Theme.liquid has the reference to the my javascript file. Moreover, the theme has reference to lquery.min.js and it is included before my javascript file.

```
{% include 'oldIE-js' %}

{{ '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}
{{ 'modernizr.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

{{ 'readjson.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

I have checked the below shopify document, yet I am not clear, what additional things I have to do. https://docs.shopify.com/api/unlinked/using-javascript-responsibly

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Edited **

As per the shopify instruction I have copied the below code to load an execute jquery. However, the code is still not working, when I debugged, the control is goint till loadscript("//ajax...) after thatno idea what is happening. I tried try-catch to display the error but I am getting none.

```
function loadjquery(){  
alert("hi");
var loadScript = function(url, callback){

var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState){  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                script.readyState == "complete"){
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {  //Others
    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    };
}

};  
var myAppJavaScript = function($){
/* Your app's JavaScript here.
   $ in this scope references the jQuery object we'll use.
   Don't use 'jQuery', or 'jQuery191', here. Use the dollar sign
   that was passed as argument.*/
$('body').append('<p>Your app is using jQuery version '+$.fn.jquery+'</p>');
};

if ((typeof jQuery === 'undefined') || (parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery) < 1.7)) {
  loadScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', function(){
    jQuery191 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    myAppJavaScript(jQuery191);
  });
} else {
  myAppJavaScript(jQuery);
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is way off the mark.
All you need for the jQuery portion is: `<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>` You don't need a loader or script tags.

Comment: @bknights, that part of line is already there but still Jquery is not executing.

Comment: Do you have this on a publicly accessible Shopify page?

Comment: I personally aviod using JQuery on shopify script tags as much as possible. I found it to be problematic. When I took the time to write in vanilla JS, it seems to stop all the problems I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what they said: [Use jQuery responsibly](https://docs.shopify.com/api/unlinked/using-javascript-responsibly#use-jquery)

You must load jQuery manually.

Try in jsfiddle.com site to select `No wrap - in <head>` from **Frameworks & Extensions**

The default option is `onLoad`

You must load jQuery library manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to web programing hence not able to understand it. I thought, including the Jquery lib in head is enough. Having said that, I followed the instructions as given in code, yet I am not able to call Jquery.

Comment: Welcome, Try include this script in your site: <script src="https://gist.github.com/lulessa/a0f112dcb816bf1ccbd6.js"></script>
Also you can download it and permanently include it
Link to github: https://gist.github.com/lulessa/a0f112dcb816bf1ccbd6

Comment: I just had one question ( I am most likely missing something). The code in the link is similar to what I have except the fact that code is self executing anonymous function,so that it executes immediately. However in my case the code needs to execute after drop-down is changed. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is included in all Shopify pages by default, you don't have to include the file once again.

Check in console if jQuery is loaded. If it is not loaded, then you need to include the file.

If it is loaded, try using `onchange="alert('hi')"` in the element to check if at all the change is actually is happening. If you get the alert, try to bind the element by `$('.....').on("change",function(){alert('hi')}` and check. If this is working try logging the error. You should figure out immediately where the issue is.